# enable-migrations not woking in Entity Framework 5 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-shell

I am trying to learn MVC4 with entity framework 5 using visual studio 2013 ultimate edition (Update 4) in code first approach, But in enable-migration command , i am getting following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Even I have installed **vs_isoshell.exe** as recommended by some people/website, still facing same issue.

Comment: The best thing to do is leave MVC4 and just leap into MVC5 with EF6. There is no reason different than your boss that justify learning MVC4. This stuff in MVC4 tutorials will work in MVC5(95% of it), don't worry.

Comment: thanks,This solution i kn :) . just want to kn the solution or any work around.

Comment: Ok, I checked it myself in ASP.NET-MVC4 web application with forms authentication. I got VS2013 Update 4. No problems whatsoever: `PM> enable-migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project Mvc4Application.`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it might be caused by .NET Framework 4 installation.
Follow these:

- Ensure to unable your anti-virus and some security software,
  perhaps, to close your firewall.
- Try to clean your "%temp%" folder (Start Menu >> Run >> Type
  "%temp%")
- Reinstall .NET Framework 4